# creating ticket with GAS through Zendesk api - \n not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, zendesk-api

Hello I'm trying to make a zendesk ticket via zendesk api with Google Apps Scripts.

I made a message body to post but "\n" is not working properly when it's posted.

For example, I make the following message body.

`"This is a first line of the ticket","\n","This is a second line of the ticket","\n"`

Then I expect it to come out like below

> This is a first line of the ticket
>
> This is a second line of the ticket

But what I actually get is

> This is a first line of the ticket
>
>
> This is a second line of the ticket

I don' need an empty row in between but it shows that way.
I've checked html but there is only one "br" in between.
I'd like to know the reason why this happens.
Thanks.

Comment: what happens if you remove the `\n`s ?

Comment: @DmitryKostyuk Thanks for the comment. I get just one sentence without any line break they are put together...

Comment: When you remove the `\n`s are your sentences still different comma-separated strings?

Comment: We need a minimal reproducible example here

Comment: It's just like this `This is a first line of the ticketThis is a second line of the ticket`